# in Xcode can you have it automatically highlight references to the selected object like in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, xcode

In Eclipse when you click on a method name a variable, or an object for example, the same ones are highlighted in a specific color elsewhere in the code for easy finding.

Is there a similar feature in Xcode?

Comment: Hi here's my similar answer on another thread,it have an solution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31214118/5030846

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can highlight them using a find operation:

If you've selected a word, hit Cmd+E (find based on current selection), Cmd+F (show the find bar), then Cmd+G (find next). You can become very productive in Xcode (or any other OS X app for that matter) through judicious use of Cmd+E, Cmd+F and Cmd+G.

Answer (score 7):

If you count underlining as highlighting I would say "yes". 
If you select the Variable and keep the cursor there, Xcode will underline all other instanced of that variable.

Comment: Apple should know… If you going to do something, do it well! The underline is a lame attempt at highlighting. I say, highlight properly or not at all!

Comment: Apple's highlight is soo poor that I'll always use CTRL + G.

Comment: @BradThomas - I agree. The whole Xcode is a lame attempt to create an IDE.