# Make Xcode highlight selected symbol more

Tags: xcode

Xcode underlines all occurrences of a symbol that the cursor is on. However, the underline doesn't exactly "pop out" in the source code. Is it possible to make Xcode highlight the background color of the symbol, like Eclipse does it? I can't find anything in the Preferences panel.

Xcode:

[image: Xcode]

Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: Have you, by any chance, figured out the answer?

Comment: @courteous Nope. But I hope that post-4.4 Xcode updates will bring some improvements in this area.

Comment: Cmd+E, Cmd+F and Cmd+G combo is usefull.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439701/in-xcode-can-you-have-it-automatically-highlight-references-to-the-selected-obje

Comment: Depending on why you want to do this, edit all in scope (Ctrl-Cmd-E) may be helpful.

Comment: @CuriousRabbit yes, that is the closest thing I have found. Thanks.

Comment: @TomA Cmd+E Cmd+G combo is enough.

Comment: Be sure to look for (and vote up) Balazs Vadnai's answer below. It is the only CORRECT solution posted.

Comment: As of Xcode 12 and the demise of Alcatraz, highlighting the symbol the cursor is on is subtle, but it does work. Note that double clicking on a symbol and selecting it will **not** highlight other instances, but _single clicking on a symbol to place the cursor inside it_ **will** highlight other instances of the symbol.

Answer (score 20):

XCode already has this feature but there's a delay on it after you **single click** on the text you want to highlight. You can set the delay to 0 seconds.

XCode > Preferences > TextEditing > HighlightInstancesOfSelected and set Delay to 0s

This works but I wasn't able to change the color of it. It is a pale blue color and a bit hard to see.

Comment: It works perfectly fine, but it's a bit odd after years of using JetBrains products where **double click** was triggering highlight.

Comment: Have you found a way to change the color?

Comment: It doesn't display any kind of highlight for the selected variable.

Answer (score 10):

Search for `AutoHighlightSymbol` <strike>in [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/) (Xcode's package manager)</strike>. It will do exactly what you want.

After you have the plugin installed, select Editor > Edit Highlight Color. This is transparent by default, so you have to pick one that suits your color theme best.

EDIT: Now that Alcatraz is gone, you're going to have to install the plugin manually. Download from [their GitHub](https://github.com/chiahsien/AutoHighlightSymbol), build the project and restart Xcode - which needs to be unsigned for being able to load 3rd party bundles. More info on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38814459/4787203).

Comment: Thanks - I just installed AutoHightlightSymbol. It was very easy to install the Alcatraz Package Manager (which I had to Google to figure out what you were talking about). It's a little unintuitive that the default preferences are to not highlight the symbols but after reading the AutoHightlightSymbol github readme I have it working. THANK YOU!

Comment: I wrongly thought that the package manager comes with Xcode, that's why I didn't explain it further. I have edited the answer, thanks!

Comment: This is the best plugin, since it relies on the "highlight selected symbol" feature of Xcode, so comments and so forth are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but you may want to check out the [Polychromatic](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/Polychromatic) Xcode plugin (most easily installed via [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io)). It gives every symbol a unique color, which is used consistently throughout. So every instance of `myVar` might be blue, and every instance of `myOtherVar` might be red.

Comment: it is offtop. We need a selection in cursor position, not simply more bright colors in code

Answer (score 1):

This plugin does what you want. It's available through [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io):

https://github.com/keepyounger/HighlightSelectedString

Comment: Unfortunately not. What Xcode does with the underline is showing occurrences of this variable **in the current scope**. This plugin simply RegExes over the source and highlights everything with the same content. It's not half as useful.
Mind that you have one scope per if, for example. This can't be handled by this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but when you hover with the cursor on a symbol a small selection menu shows up and you can select "Edit All in Scope". This highlights all such symbols in a much more visible way. As the name suggests, this functionality is meant for a higher purpose, but I think it comes in handy even just for highlighting.
I don't know if this feature was available before Xcode 5.

Comment: Thanks. That's what Ctrl-Cmd-E does as @CuriousRabbit suggested, see comments below question. I now use this regularly when I need to highlight a symbol.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Anyway, I also have been fighting this since forever... I hope future releases will provide such an obvious an useful feature.

Answer (score -1):

community!

I have the same trouble and found something like that. (where the "currencyId" i select,another its work of plugin)

[image]

Its, i guess, do the same thing like [**Cmd+E**, **Cmd+F** and **Cmd+G** combo]
But its easier,you must only select word in your code.

How to **install** it to Your XCode:

1. Launch XCode
2. On top menu select Window->Package Manager
3. In
   search type "**highlightSelectedString**"
   [image]
4. Install it!
5. ?
6. Profit

And also you can change **color** of highlighting!!!

1. go to Edit->Set Highlight color
2. Choose your color

Comment: Unfortunately not. What Xcode does with the underline is showing occurrences of this variable **in the current scope**. This plugin simply RegExes over the source and highlights everything with the same content. It's not half as useful.
Mind that you have one scope per if, for example. This can't be handled by this plugin.

Answer (score -3):

ok go to xcode 
select preferences
pop over will come select fonts and colors
down u can see 4 buttons,with 1 having name selection,click and choose any deep color

Comment: he doesnt want that but he wants to highlight the currently 'selected' symbol