# Highlight current line in Xcode 4 editor?

Tags: xcode, line, highlight

Unless I've overlooked it, there isn't such an option in Xcode 4 preferences. Is there any way (extension, plugin, etc.) to achieve this visual feedback?

Google search on ["xcode 4 highlight current line"](https://www.google.si/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=sl&sclient=psy-ab&q=xcode%204%20highlight%20current%20line&oq=xcode%204%20highlight%20current%20line&aq=f&aqi=g-L1&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3..0i19.993561.994697.3.995272.5.5.0.0.0.0.257.647.3j1j1.5.0.kneXqqi4-ic&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c4824870849d112f&ion=1) is in vain ...

Or was there a deliberate omission of this (rudimentary) feature?

### Related question

Also, if anybody can answer [a question on (symbol) selection highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333509/make-xcode-highlight-selected-symbol-more), please do so.

### Installing *CurrentLineHighlighter.dylib* issue

After executing these two

```
$  defaults write /PATH/TO/Xcode.app/Contents/Info LSEnvironment -dict DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES /PATH/TO/CurrentLineHighlighter.dylib

$  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /PATH/TO/Xcode.app
```

`Xcode` stopped working (and `Spotlight` can't find `Xcode` as well).

The `/PATH/TO/CurrentLineHighlighter.dylib` was actually inside Xcode's `Contents` folder: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/CurrentLineHighlighter.dylib`

Comment: Actually, the second link on google (your search pattern) offers the sources for a dylib that does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @Till, I've (mistakenly it seems) thought this was only for the `eero` (programming language). Will give it a shot.

Comment: See my answer - it includes all sources and a binary version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm the author of that (old) code. A more current (and safer) version of it is now part of [Xcode4-Fixins](https://github.com/davekeck/Xcode-4-Fixins). It is MUCH easier to deal with, since it's actually an Xcode plugin.

Comment: +1 Great to see it being incorporated into a proper plugin. Thanks for sharing!