# How to show the cursor's current line & column position in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, text-editor

How do you view the cursor's current line and column position in Xcode? This is irrespective of showing the Line Numbers on the active sheet's left side, how can you show 'Line, Column', or look it up.

Here is an example from Eclipse -

[image]

Comment: Not really, you can turn on the `Page guide at column: 80`

Comment: Bummer! Thank you for your response! I use the character address to align side-comments :)

Comment: Suppose you know how to turn on the line number. :)

Comment: one the left-side of the active sheet? Yup!

Comment: I know not an answer to your question (from what I can tell there is no option to display line/col of cursor in Xcode) but for what it's worth I use AppCode from JetBrains.  I don't see many mentions of it here on SO but it really is a nice IDE for iOS dev.  Same feel and same types of functionality as IntelliJ Idea for Java development.  It does show cursor pos BTW.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/limejelly/Backlight-for-XCode)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258003/highlight-current-line-in-xcode-4-editor

Answer (score 4):

Too my knowledge, showing column number has been removed from new versions of Xcode. You can see line number and set column guide in text editor setting though.

If you are coding in c/c++ I strongly suggest switching to [QtCreator](http://www.qt.io/ide/) or [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/). I personally prefer QtCreator since 1) it has a fakeVim key binding and 2) it is better at loading symbols and giving autocomplete suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Xcode plugin: [Backlight for Xcode](https://github.com/limejelly/Backlight-for-XCode)

You can use [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/) to easily install this plugin, another way of installing it is to:

1. Download source
2. Build code
3. Restart Xcode
4. (Check Github page on how to further configure the plugin)