# Xcode Editor: Highlight instance of selected symbol

Tags: xcode, editor, codehighlighter, xcode9.3-beta

Xcode does not highlight the selected instance in the editor.

Xcode - Text Editing preference has an option to enable/disable selected code/symbol highlight. And it's enabled there, but it still doesn't work in the editor.

[image]

Here is a snapshot of my editor code, with the selected instance.

[image]

I'm using [Xcode 9.3-beta2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-9-2-9-3-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-d/44390183#44390183).

Here is a similar question, but it's related to changing the highlight color: [Make Xcode highlight selected symbol more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333509/make-xcode-highlight-selected-symbol-more)

Comment: This will be an Xcode 9.3 bug IMO. It works for me with Xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try just to click on a symbol? If I do that it will highlight all instances. Below I just placed the cursor on `NSNotificationCenter` by clicking on it. So, do *not* select the word, only place the cursor in it.

[image]

Comment: You can see in snapshot - `largelabel` instance is already selected.

Comment: Yes, my point is it should _not_ be selected, but just have the cursor in it.

Comment: How can I change the highlight color?